# reference of code to static doesnt find any implementation

Tags: php, static-members, magic-methods

I have in code this

```
/**
* @method static \string myMethod()
*/
```

I dont see myMethod() define anywhere but I see a usage

```
static::myMethod();
```

what am I missing here.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Or parent classes?